# How should a React component call a function in a collection of homogenous children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, reference

Say I have a component that contains functionality to send PUT requests to my backend. Normally, these requests are triggered by the user interacting with this component directly. Let's call this `Child`.

A different part of my UI contains a collection of these elements rendered in a parent component. Let's call this new container `Parent`.

I want `Parent` to have a common button rendered next to the collection of `Child` components that lets my user trigger PUT requests from all `Child` elements in one go.

Currently, I save refs of each `Child` element as I render each of them in `Parent`. When the user clicks the common button rendered in `Parent`, I have `Parent` iterate over each ref and invoke the function in each `Child` that triggers the PUT request. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a better way. You should [lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the nearest common ancestor that needs to access it. In this case, you have data in each `Child` that needs to be accessible within the `Parent`. You're trying *too hard* to make Children completely independent entities which are disconnected from their container.

Instead, I'd suggest rethinking the structure of your app so that the data lives inside of `Parent` or another ancestor as `state`, and that ancestor simply passes it down to each `Child` as `props` for rendering. The function that does the `PUT` request can optionally also live inside of the ancestor and be handled with a callback, or - depending on the what feedback needs to happen or not happen from that callback - simply be a utility function or service which is shared across components.

Edit: this is one of the core concepts of React and is called "top-down data flow". [From the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lessons-learned):

> There should be a single “source of truth” for any data that changes in a React application. Usually, the state is first added to the component that needs it for rendering. Then, if other components also need it, you can lift it up to their closest common ancestor. Instead of trying to sync the state between different components, you should rely on the top-down data flow.